# How can I send an email from the command line using blat when the body contains carriage returns and line feeds?

Tags: windows, email, smtp, blat

I have a windows server which sends emails to me through a BASIC program.  If the message body contains carriage returns/line feeds then the email never finishes.  Only the first line is sent to me.  I tried replacing them with \n but that didn't help as the email came to me with the \n in it.  Any ideas?

Here is the command I'm using:

```
blat -to mike.roosa@toltsg.com -subject "[DEV] PO Detail Report" -body "Attached file
is ready for import.
From 01/01/09 to 01/29/09 
PO Status not egual to 'C'" -attach "C:\TXT\PODetail_26879.csv" -log
C:\EMAIL.LOG\20090129.TXT -timestamp'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it all inline use the '|' character

```
-body 1st line|second line|third line
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put the body in a text file and have blat send that:

```
blat [text file here] -to mike.roosa@toltsg.com -subject "[DEV] PO Detail Report" -attach "C:\TXT\PODetail_26879.csv" -log
C:\EMAIL.LOG\20090129.TXT -timestamp'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use Mail Alert Simple Mailer:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mail-alert/

MailAlert.exe -r address@example.com -b "@Your_Directory\File_with_Mail_Body.txt"

You can also attach HTML file as an email body (remember to change PlaintextOnly=no in such a case).